# SQL update a column to equal a column from a join and using a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which handles stock and have been getting out of sync recently.

The data needs to be updated to be in sync again and `tableB` is always correct so we base the update on this  table and use the data from this table to update `tableA`.

I am attempting to update via a join.

With the below code I have tried multiple different ways to update, for example using a where statement on the `xcolumn2`, removing the selecting part etc.

Is there a piece of syntax I am missing or am I going the wrong way about it?

```
update tableA
set tableA.columnA = tableB.columnA

--select
--tableA.xcolumn2,
--tableA.columnA,
--tableB.columnA, 

--from tableA as tableA
left join 
(select xcolumn1, xcolumn2, sum(columnA) as columnA, sum(xcolumn3) as xcolumn3 
from tableB as tableB group by xcolumn1, xcolumn2) as tableB
on tableA.xcolumn2 = tableB.xcolumn2


group by 
tableA.xcolumn2,
tableA.columnA, 
tableB.columnA,
having sum(tableA.columnA) != sum(tableB.columnA)
```

Comment: You can't use group by (or having) in an update

Comment: I think you can get rid of last 5 lines. As already told by @t-clause.dk that `GROUP BY` is not permitted here. Also, how would it matter if the update happens even if `sum(tableA.columnA)` is equal to `sum(tableB.columnA)`. Would it matter? Let me know. Apart from it other syntical errors can be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine your update should look something like this:

```
UPDATE  tableA
SET     tableA.columnA = tableB.columnA
FROM    tableA
JOIN    ( SELECT   xcolumn1 ,
                   xcolumn2 ,
                   SUM(columnA) AS columnA
          FROM     tableB AS tableB
          GROUP BY xcolumn1 ,
                   xcolumn2
        ) AS tableB 
ON tableA.xcolumn2 = tableB.xcolumn2
AND tableA.xcolumn1 = tableB.xcolumn1
AND (tableA.columnA <> tableB.columnA
     OR tableA.columnA IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks @t-clause.dk that works better - unfortunately I am unable to up vote at present